# Get hid_t and path-in-file of H5::DataSet to use H5OCopy

Tags: c++, hdf5

I'm using the C++ wrapper library over HDF5, and want to drop down to the C API
to efficiently copy a dataset from a source HDF5 file into a destination one. (in a different path, but that's beside the point).

I have access to the low-level ID and path for the destination, but for the
source I only have the H5::DataSet C++ wrapper instance, while H5Ocopy() (see below for the prototype) requires the hid_t of the source HDF5 file that contains the dataset **and** its path in that source file.

Is there a way to get the missing file-hid_t and dataset-path from the H5::DataSet instance?

Intuitively I think there must be, but I'm not finding them up to that point. --DD

PS: It would be quite difficult to *surface* those id/path through the layers of APIs, from the point where they are known, since the code that wants to do the H5OCopy is very *distant in time and space*.

```
H5_DLL herr_t H5Ocopy(
  hid_t src_loc_id, const char *src_name,
  hid_t dst_loc_id, const char *dst_name,
  hid_t ocpypl_id, hid_t lcpl_id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is an option for you, take a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it may greatly alleviate the way to copy a dataset from one HDF5 file into another. As an example, to copy a dataset called `dset` from file `one.h5` into file `two.h5` just do the following in C++ using HDFql:

```
HDFql::execute("COPY DATASET one.h5 dset TO two.h5 dset");
```

Additionally, you may copy `dset` into another group (from file `two.h5`) and give the dataset another name, example:

```
HDFql::execute("COPY DATASET one.h5 dset TO two.h5 /group/new_dset");
```

For additional information and examples check HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf).

Comment: First, the source H5File is not a *file*, since uses a custom VFL, and second as the question mentioned, I do not have the name/path of the source dataset, so I'm not too sure how that would help. Using H5Ocopy is simple enough, if/when you have the right arguments, and what you suggest does not seem to help, given the questions I already asked. Introduce a DSL on top of HDF5 is only going to slow things down IMHO, unless I'm missing something. Thanks for the link though.